# Conceal LaTeX's \index command in Vim

Tags: vim, latex

How can I use the conceal feature in Vim to conceal the `\index` command in LaTeX?

The command takes one argument within braces with arbitrary content (but without newline character), i.e. `\index{...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember finding this in a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3eqz1e/latex_footnote_text_syntax_highlighting/cthk9ox):

```
syn match texStatement /\\index{[^}]*}\+/ conceal cchar=⚓
```

(this "replaces" everything - the command & the key  - with the anchor character)